# Inserting scanner input directly into arraylist

Tags: java

I wanted to extract input from my scanner and insert it directly into a typesafe arraylist. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<Integer> arglist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> resultlist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Scanning");
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        arglist.add(in.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("Scan complete, sorting...");
    System.out.println(arglist);
    resultlist=qksort(arglist);
    System.out.println(resultlist);

}
```

This works only when I explicitly terminate input using Ctrl+Z. Shouldn't the stream terminate when I press "Enter"?

Comment: No with `System.in`. It will work with a file as input, but with `System.in` you will only have the EOF flag set when you hit Ctrl + Z. 
Your `while` body will run any time you press Enter, for every word in the line, but the `hasNext` method will wait for the OS return again, so, unless you terminate the console input, it will wait forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't terminate when you press the enter key. The scanner will read that as a newline character and interpret it as a delimiter between tokens and happily continue.

A very simple solution if you want to continue processing is:

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    argList.add(in.nextInt());
}
```

That way the first time you type something that isn't a number or whitespace (e.g. "exit") it will continue.

If you particularly want to just input a single line then you can use the scanner to read a line and then scan that line:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
```

Comment: *"The scanner will read that as a newline character and happily continue."* To be more precise ... it ignores the newline character. Like `hasNextInt`.

Comment: @Tom it will still consider it a delimiter for the purpose of defining a token right? I'm not sure what you mean by ignoring it - isn't it treated like any other whitespace?

Comment: @Tom I realised it was a bit ambiguous so tried to make it clearer in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that is better. `next()` doesn't care about whitespace and doesn't read them. It waits for valid tokens. `nextLine()` on the other hand handles new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

If End of Stream didn't appear as in case of Files or 'Ctrl + Z' in case of standard input, then hasNext() method is blocking...it means-

Either it finds pattern in buffer: in this case it return True.

Or if it goes for reading from underline stream: in this case it might block.